# How to avoid flickering after auto refresh

Tags: javascript, canvas

Can you please tell me how to stop flickering on images drawn on canvas after auto refreshing. 
This is my code

```
 <script>
  setTimeout(data1, 0);
  function data1(){
 for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
 {
   var canvas=document.getElementById('map'+id);
   context=canvas.getContext("2d");
   context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(response[0][3])+"Helllooooo");
   $.ajax({
   url : "/getData?id="+data[i][3],
   type : "GET",
   data : null,
   datatype : "JSON",
   success : function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) 
   { 
      for(var j=0;j<response[0].length;j++)
      {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response[0][j]+"Hello"));
      }
      console.log(i+" "+response)
      if(response[0][7]=="1")
      {
          console.log("Status 1");
          context.drawImage(image_red, response[0][1], response[0][2]); 
      }
      if(response[0][7]=="2")
      {
          console.log("Status 2");
          context.drawImage(image_green,response[0][1],response[0][2]);
      }
  }
 });
 }
}
setInterval(data1,5000);
}
```

In above code I'm getting flickering after auto refresh. Kindly help me.

Thanks and Regards,
Mujahid Ateeb Khan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put the `clearRect` call insude the success callback. The flicker you see is caused by clearing the context way before you redraw it. By putting it into the success callback it will happen in the same microtask, so no flicker will be visible.

Comment: Thank You So much I got the result from you... It works fine now. I removed clearRect